# Como fazer migrations para uma base de dados não default

Tags: mysql, python, django

Estou a desenvolver um site em django em que me deu jeito utilizar a base de dados dos CTT com os seus códigos postais. Consegui encontrar uma base de dados com isso tudo e incluir no meu projeto.
Segui a política de não incluir essa base de dados na base de dados default do meu site, logo, no ficheiro settings do meu projeto, tenho:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'bio_jose',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
},
'codigos_postais': {
    'NAME': 'codigos_postais',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
},
```

}

So far, so good e ainda não tinha encontrado problemas com esta abordagem. Encontrei algures forma de criar o código para estes models automaticamente e consegui trabalhar com a base de dados até com o django REST-API framework onde faço consultas com Javascript sem problemas para obter o que pretendo.
Agora surgiu-me a necessidade de acrescentar um campo a um dos models desta base de dados dos códigos postais, mas não consigo correr o comando ***makemigrations*** para a mesma.
Os seus models estão declarados numa app que se chama api pois não esperava usá-la para além do frontend e se correr o comando:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations --database=codigos_postais
```

A resposta dele é a esperada pois não aceita o argumento **database**:

```
manage.py makemigrations: error: unrecognized arguments: --database=codigos_postais
```

Se tentar correr o mesmo comando mas indicando a app que quero atualizar, ou seja, onde se encontram os models para a base de dados (api):

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations api
```

A resposta surge como:

```
No changes detected in app 'api'
```

Pese embora eu já tenha acrescentado um campo no model que quero alterar. Isto se ocorrer numa qualquer app que utilize a base de dados default, corre bem, mas nesta não consigo aplicar as alterações na base de dados MySQL...
Tenho um Router que configurei na altura da importação da base de dados que tem o seguinte:

```
class MyRouter(object):
"""
Um router serve para controlar qual a base de dados a ser utilizada pelos modelos das nossas aplicações
"""

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Tenta ler modelos de códigos postais para irem para a base de dados codigos_postais
    :param model:
    :param hints:
    :return:
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'codigos_postais':
        return 'codigos_postais'
    elif model._meta.app_label == 'bio_main' or model._meta.app_label == 'accounts':
        return 'default'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Tenta escrever modelos de códigos postais na base de dados codigos_postais
    :param model:
    :param hints:
    :return:
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'codigos_postais':
        return 'codigos_postais'
    elif model._meta.app_label == 'bio_main' or model._meta.app_label == 'accounts':
        return 'default'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Permite relações se um modelo de códigos postais está envolvido
    :param obj1:
    :param obj2:
    :param hints:
    :return:
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'codigos_postais' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'codigos_postais':
        return True
    elif 'codigos_postais' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
        return True
    return False

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Verifica que os modelos de códigos postais apenas aparecem nesta base de dados
    :param db:
    :param app_label:
    :param model_name:
    :param hints:
    :return:
    """
    if app_label == 'codigos_postais':
        return db == 'codigos_postais'
    elif app_label == 'bio_main' or app_label == 'accounts':
        return db == 'default'
    return True
```

E a questão é:
Como é que consigo correr o comando **makemigrations** e posterior **migrate** numa base de dados que não a default?
Obrigado amigos, saúde para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Para o `makemigrations` você pode selecionar o `app`, ou seja:

```
python manage.py makemigrations seu_app_aqui
```

Já para o `migrate`, por padrão ele usa o *default*, porém você pode escolher o database usando o `--database` conforme abaixo:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=codigos_postais
```

Para maiores detalhes veja [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, depois de ter acabado por ter acrescentado um campo à mão, cheguei à documentação certa para resolver o meu problema.
O que aconteceu foi que eu gerei o meu ficheiro `models.py` automáticamente a partir de uma base de dados já existente que primeiramente apenas queria utilizar como API e nesse código gerado automáticamente, está uma opção na classe `Meta` que diz:

```
managed = False
```

E aqui é que está o problema. Com `managed = False`, esta tabela não fica disponível para o `Manager` e consequentemente para todas as operações de migração.